# Написал систему бонусов для ранера в Unity. Насколько правильно я это сделал?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Я новичок в unity и мне нужен совет правильно ли я делаю, и если нет то интересно что не так и как будет лучше с точки зрения архитектуры кода. Код работает.

Абстрактный класс самого бонуса

```
public abstract class BonusPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private float _duration;
  [SerializeField] private Sprite _icon;
  [SerializeField] private AudioClip _soundEffect;
  [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem _specialEffect;

  protected Player Player;
  private AudioSource _audioSource;

  protected float Duration { get => _duration; set => _duration = value; }
  protected Sprite Icon { get => _icon; set => _icon = value; }

  private void Start()
  {
    _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
  }
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
     if (other.TryGetComponent(out Player player))
     {
        Player = player;
        StartBonus();
     }
  }
  public virtual void StartBonus()
  {
    if (_specialEffect != null)
    {
        Instantiate(_specialEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation, transform);
    }

    if (_soundEffect != null)
    {
        _audioSource.clip = _soundEffect;
        _audioSource.Play();
    }
    StartCoroutine(TimeBonusAction());
  }

  public IEnumerator TimeBonusAction()
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_duration);

    StopBonus();
  }
  public virtual void StopBonus()
  {
    StopCoroutine(SoundTimer());
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
  }
```

Код уже конкретного бонуса для увеличения количества очков

```
public class BonusScore : BonusPlayer
{
 [SerializeField] private int _bonusScore;

 public override void StartBonus()
 {
    base.StartBonus();
    Player.ShowBonusUi(Icon, Duration);
    Player.BonusScore(_bonusScore);
 }

 public override void StopBonus()
 {
    base.StopBonus();
    Player.BonusScoreEnd();
 }  

}
```

И код отображения иконки подобранного бонуса на экране

```
public class BonusUI : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _canvasGroup;
  [SerializeField] private Text _textDuration;
  [SerializeField] private Image _iconBonus;
  [SerializeField] private Player Player;

private float _duration;
private void Update()
{
    _textDuration.text = _duration.ToString("0");
    _duration -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (_duration < 0)
    {
        _canvasGroup.alpha = 0;
    }
}
private void OnEnable()
{
    Player.ShowBonusIcon += ShowBonus;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    Player.ShowBonusIcon -= ShowBonus;
}

public void ShowBonus(Sprite icon, float duration)
{
    _canvasGroup.alpha = 1;
    _duration = duration;
    _iconBonus.sprite = icon;
}   }
```

Скрипт отображения иконки подобранного бонуса на экран, вызывается через событие в скрипте Player
больше всего интересует правильно ли у меня это реализовано.
Или лучше делать вывод на экран не касаясь скрипта игрока?

код класса Player

```
 public void ShowBonusUi(Sprite icon, float duration)
{
    ShowBonusIcon?.Invoke(icon, duration);
}

public void BonusScore(int bonus)
{
    _scoreMultiplae = bonus;

}
public void BonusScoreEnd()
{
    _scoreMultiplae = 3;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начинающего не плохо. Но ответственность каждого класса размыта.

- `BonusPlayer`, имеет данные о длительности, визуализации, сам себя собирает, активирует и деактивирует, пиццу заказывает, детей из детского сада забирает... многовато!
- `BonusUI` по идее занимается отображением, но сам вычисляет время и работает без конечно...
- `Player`... почему он вообще занимается UI?

---

Нужен объект трека который можно собирать:

```
// collectable item model 
public abstract class CollectableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnCollect;

    public void Collect ()
    {
        OnCollect?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

`_soundEffect` и `_specialEffect` не нужны, потому что их можно запустить через событие, и не только их, а все что угодно, хоть настройки материала поменять, хоть вообще без ничего.
Подоранный предмет может быть чем угодно, `100gold`, хоть `10xp`, `_duration` и `_icon` тут тоже лишние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

То что отличает именно бафы.

```
public interface IBuff
{
    BuffData Data { get; }
    float elapsed { get; }
}

// collectable buff model 
public class CollectableBuff : CollectableItem
{
    [SerializeField] private BuffData _data;
    
    public BuffData Data => _data;

    public IBuff Buff { get; }
}

// набор данных связан, образуя вместе единицу и передается пакетом,
// как например в UI визуализацию, поэтому нет смысла их разделять
[Serializable]
public struct BuffData
{
    public string title;
    public Sprite icon;
    public float duration;
}
```

Наследники могут быть бонусами абсолютно любого типа.

```
// multiply all score income
public class ScoreMultiplayerBuff : CollectableBuff
{
    [SerializeField] private float _multilayer;

    public float Multiplayer => _multilayer;

    public IBuff Buff => new MultiplayerModifier(Data, _multilayer);
}

// add score to each monster kill
public class KillScoreBonusBuff : CollectableBuff
{
    [SerializeField] private float _amount;

    public float Amount => _amount;

    public IBuff Buff => new KillModifier(Data, _amount);
}
```

---

Сбор предметов это отдельная ответственность, ни как не связанная с `Player` чья задача бежать, прыгать и т.д.

```
// collect collectable items
public class Collector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private BuffHandler _buff;
    [SerializeField] private Wallet _wallet;
    [SerializeField] private Inventory _inventory;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out CollectableItem item))
        {
            if (item is CollectableBuff buff)
                OnCollect(buff);
            else if (item is CollectableCurrency currency)
                OnCollect(currency);
            else if (item is CollectableResources resources)
                OnCollect(resources);
            OnCollect(item);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollect (CollectableBuff buff)
    {
        _buff.Add(buff.Buff);
    }

    private void OnCollect (CollectableCurrency currency)
    {
        _wallet.Add(currency.type, currency.amount);
    }

    private void OnCollect (CollectableResources resources)
    {
        _inventory.Add(resources.content);
    }
}
```

---

У тебя бафф подбирал и обрабатывал сам себя, а `BuffUI` не имел с ним никакой связи. Должен быть обработчик бафов, занимающийся их жизненным циклом, а визуализация в интерфейсе и обработка эффекта уже головняк других классов, о которых обработчик и знать не знает.

```
// handles the life cycle of buffs
public class BuffHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // BuffView подписывается на эти события и занимается только отображением
    // Еще нужен обработчик который проверяет бафы на типы и отправляет кому нужно,
    // например, если IBuff это ScoreModifier (MultiplayerModifier, KillModifier),
    // то он передается ScoreHandler обрабатывающйи получение очков,
    // подобно Collector который разделяет суп и мух на более верхнем уровне CollectableItem
    public Action<IBuff> OnAdded;
    public Action<IBuff> OnExpired;
    private List<IBuff> _buffs;

    public void Start ()
    {
        _buffs = new List<IBuff>();
    }

    public void Add (IBuff buff)
    {
        _buffs.Add(buff);
        OnAdded?.Invoke(buff);
    }

    public void Expired (IBuff buff)
    {
        _buffs.Remove(buff);
        OnExpired?.Invoke(buff);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // for с конца поскольку истекшие бафы удаляются
        for (int i = _buffs.Count-1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            IBuff buff = _buffs[i];
            buff.elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            if (buff.elapsed >= buff.Data.duration)
                Expired(buff);
        }
    }
}
```

---

п.с. классы типа `BuffHandler`, `ScoreHandler`, `Wallet`, `Inventory` не обязательно должны быть `MonoBehaviour`.

---

Закрытости и наследование хромает

- делать `protected F get/set` свойство для `private _f`
  это тоже самое, что поставить самому полю `_f` модификатор доступа `protected`, атрибут `[SerializeField]` на него так-же распространяется.
- наследники `BonusPlayer`, могут делать с полем `protected Player` что вздумается, хотя по задумке не должны, свойство, позволяющее только `protected  get` отсутствует и поле должно быть `private`, либо без поля и только свойство `protected Player { get; private set; }`.
- `virtual M()` метод плохая практика, из-за того, что в наследнике может не быть `base.M()`. Если базовое выполнение обязательно, то пускай `M()` в конце себя вызывает пустой метод `virtual/abstract OnM()` и у наследника не будет такого выбора, который ему не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь